# Moose: injecting parameters into construction

Tags: perl, constructor, moose

I have a filename attribute that has attached validation. Now when the filename isn't specified during construction I want to read it from a configuration file.

```
subtype 'filename'
        => as 'Str'
        => where { -r $_ }
        => message { "$_ is not a readable file" };

has 'students_file' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'filename', default => '' );
has 'teachers_file' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'filename', default => '' );
```

The issue is that `BUILD` seems to be run after the validation occurs. All examples of `BUILDARGS` seem to handle a different way of constructing the object.

So where should I read the configuration and set the attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give `teachers_file` and `students_file` `builder` methods (or inline `default` subs) that set them from the config file. The builder will only run if those attributes *aren't* provided as keys to the constructor (unless you use `init_arg => undef` to prevent them from being set in the constructor).

If your config is an attribute of its own, with a builder that reads the config file, then you have an ordering problem between `config` and `teachers_file` and `students_file`. You can resolve this by making `teachers_file` and `students_file` lazy attributes, which ensures that they won't try to be constructed before the config attribute. However, you may want to make sure that the "foo is not a readable file" error is thrown as early as possible during construction, instead of the first time the attribute is used. You can work around that by adding

```
sub BUILD {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->teachers_file;
  $self->students_file;
}
```

which ensures that those attributes are read once (and constructed) before the constructor returns.